# Finding the volume of a sculpture

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, volume

A sculpture is given by the region bounded by the two surfaces in $(x, y, z)$ space defined by $z=(x^2 +y^2-1)^2$ and $z=4$. What is the volume of the sculpture?

I attempted to find the volume by setting up the triple integral,

$\iiint_{R} dx\space dy\space dz $

since $ z=(x^2+y^2-1)^2$,

finding the bounds for $dx$:

$1=(x^2+1-1)^2$

$x=1$

finding the bounds for $dy$:

$1=(x^2+y^2-1)^2$

$y=(2-x^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}$

hence the triple integral will take the form,

$ \int_{0}^{1} dx \space\int_{0}^{(2-x^2)^{1/2}} dy \space\int_{0}^{(x^2+y^2-1)^2}dz$

I tried to evaluate this intagral starting with $\int_{0}^{(x^2+y^2-1)^2}dz$ but it gave me a very lengthy integral with no cancellations, is this a correct way for going about the problem, or is there an easier approach to finding the volume?

Comment: The integral can be evaluated by using cylindrical coordinates as follows:
\begin{align*}
\text{Volume }&=\int_{\theta=0}^{\theta=2\pi}\int_{r=0}^{r=\sqrt{3}}\int_{z=(r^2-1)^2}^{z=4}r\,dz\,dr\,d\theta
\end{align*}

Comment: How did you obtain the integral bounds for dr ? @MarioG

Comment: It is clear that $r\ge 0$ and for $z=4$ we have $(r^2-1)^2=4$, so $r^2-1=2$ which means $r^2=3$ and so $r=\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: Thanks, got it now! In cylindrical coordinates, is there ever a scenario where the bounds for $d\theta$ are not from $0$ to $2\pi$ ? @MarioG

Comment: Yes, for instance if you have a solid in the first octant, then $0\le \theta \le \pi/2$.